# ASP.MVC 4 Bundles cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web, cache-control, bundles

I migrated MVC3 to MVC4 and added mobile views for my website using JqueryMobile. To "improve" performance i am using Bundles to compres *.js and *.css files. 
[image: app_start]
everything works fine.

After deploying (system nightly build) i saw that bundle .js and .css files are being reloaded every time without using cache.
[image]

However, if i run this page on localhost host, page load size decrease from ~1mb to 450kb.
project webconfig  Debug is set to false
[image]

What could affect it. Is it posible to change directly cache-control to public?
[image]

Comment: When you say everytime, do you mean everytime you refresh the site it reloads it again? Does the unique code at the end of the  bundles change everytime you refresh?

Comment: No. Url for resource doesn't change

Comment: Why register bundles on `Session_Start()` (for each user)? It should be on `Application_Start()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this could well be an issue in Web Optimisations 1.1.2/1.1.3. Maybe reverting to 1.1.1 can fix the issue as suggested in the following post http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/127